# Rotating UIImageView around anchorpoint issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiviewanimation

I am attempting to rotate a UIImageView around an anchor point to simulate a "radar sweep" style animation. My understanding of anchor points leads me to believe that (1, 1) should be the bottom right corner of the [radar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD8pD.jpg). However, setting the ImageView's anchor point to this doesn't give me the behavior I anticipated. This can be viewed [here](https://gfycat.com/RadiantGrimyBeagle).

As can be seen, the anchor point is a ways up the right side of the image, though it is correctly at the center. What I want is the image to rotate around the center point, like a radar sweep.

Here is the relevant code:

```
self.radarView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, barDimension, barDimension)];
self.radarView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
self.radarView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"radarSweep.png"];
self.radarView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1);
self.radarView.layer.position = CGPointMake(screenWidth / 2.0, screenHeight / 2.0);
[self.mapView addSubview:self.radarView];

CABasicAnimation *opacityInAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
[opacityInAnim setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0]];
[opacityInAnim setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];
opacityInAnim.duration = 0.25;
opacityInAnim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
opacityInAnim.removedOnCompletion = NO;
opacityInAnim.beginTime = 0.0;
opacityInAnim.delegate = self;
[opacityInAnim setValue:@"radarSweep" forKey:@"animName"];

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2 * M_PI];
animation.duration = 1.0f;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animation.repeatCount = 2;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[animation setBeginTime:0.0];
animation.delegate = self;
[animation setValue:@"radarSweep" forKey:@"animName"];
animation.removedOnCompletion = YES;

CABasicAnimation *opacityOutAnimBar = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
[opacityOutAnimBar setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f]];
[opacityOutAnimBar setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]];
opacityOutAnimBar.delegate = self;
opacityOutAnimBar.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
opacityOutAnimBar.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[opacityOutAnimBar setDuration:0.25];
[opacityOutAnimBar setValue:@"radarSweep" forKey:@"animName"];
[opacityOutAnimBar setBeginTime:1.35];

CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
[group setDuration:2.0];
group.delegate = self;
group.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
group.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[group setAnimations:@[opacityInAnim, animation, opacityOutAnimBar]];
[group setValue:@"radarSweep" forKey:@"animName"];
[self.radarView.layer addAnimation:group forKey:@"group"];
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your radar image isn't square but the imageview is, so the image is bleeding over the bounds of the imageView. You can either do `self.radarView.layer.clipsToBounds = YES` or change the content mode to ScaleToFit. Or you can resize your image view to match the proportions of the radar image.

Comment: Thanks! The image used to be square, but I made a change recently and I forgot to adjust that. Looks great now!